# Rails, use schedulable gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

In my website, I have a model Shop which should have a working-hours schedule. For example,

```
Monday 11:00-18:00
Tuesday 9:00-12:00
...
```

I am using a [gem](https://github.com/benignware/schedulable) to accomplish this but I don't find its documentation very helpful... Would you, please, suggest another gem for my problem or help me resolve it by this one.
Adding

```
= f.input :schedule, as: :schedule
```

in my view only allows the user to pick the starting time.

How to allow the user to also pick the end-hour of the event using the latter 'schedulable'? Thank you!

*Edit: I do not use just a string because I would like to check if the shop is currently working.*

Answer (score 0):

the only other gem option is [recurring_select](https://github.com/GetJobber/recurring_select), but you do have to make most of the setup by yourself